# Fitting an enormous tree on a page

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I cannot fit this enormous collection of trees onto a page without the page number being obscured. Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.S  [.DP [.D some ] [.N woman ] ] [.VP  [.V hugs ] [.DP [.D every ] [.N man ] ]]]
\end{tikzpicture}




 \rotatebox{90}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), scale= 0.9]
\Tree [.S  [.DP [.D some ] [.N woman ] ] [.VP  [.V hugs ] [.DP [.D every ] [.N man ] ]]]
\end{tikzpicture} {\Huge$\Rightarrow$}
 \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center),  scale=.45]   
    \Tree [.{\formula{\exists y [woman' (y) \land [\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow hug'(y, x)]]: (t} \hspace{0.1cm}}  [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists y [woman' (y) \land Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \exists y [woman' (y) \land Q(x)] : (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda z. woman(z)$: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [.  \node (ne) {e$_{2}$}; ] [.{\formula{\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow saw'(j, x)] : t_{1} }} [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall (x) [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda$ x. x is a man: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k,m): (t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {k : e$_{2}$} ;] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m): (e_{2}  \rightarrow t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [. {\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y): (e_{3} \rightarrow (e_{2}  \rightarrow  t_{1})} } ] [. \node [circle,draw] (le) {m : e$_{3}$} ; ]  ]  ] ] ] ] ] ] ] 
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:5) and +(south:5) .. (ue); 
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:7) and +(south:7) .. (ne);
\begin{scope}[xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-10cm]
      \Tree [.{\formula{\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow[\exists y [woman' (y) \rightarrow hug'(y, x)]]: (t} \hspace{0.1cm}}  [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] : (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda z. woman(z)$: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [.  \node (ne) {e$_{2}$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists x [woman' (y) \land saw'(j, y)] : t_{1} }} [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists (y) [woman'(y) \land Q(y)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \exists (y) [P(y) \land Q(y)]: (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda$ x. x is a man: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k,m): (t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {k : e$_{2}$} ;] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m): (e_{2}  \rightarrow t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [. {\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y): (e_{3} \rightarrow (e_{2}  \rightarrow  t_{1})} } ] [. \node [circle,draw] (me) {m : e$_{3}$} ; ]  ]  ] ] ] ] ] ] ] 
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:2) and +(south:2) .. (ue); 
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:7) and +(south:7) .. (ne);
      \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture} }
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your code, I get an enormous number of errors and, eventually, a single tree on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do this but your readers will not thank you for it! It would be better to rethink how you are presenting the information (or print on A3).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\newcommand\formula[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.S  [.DP [.D some ] [.N woman ] ] [.VP  [.V hugs ] [.DP [.D every ] [.N man ] ]]]
\end{tikzpicture}


\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{\textheight}{!}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\Tree [.S  [.DP [.D some ] [.N woman ] ] [.VP  [.V hugs ] [.DP [.D every ] [.N man ] ]]]
\end{tikzpicture} {\Huge$\Rightarrow$}
 \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center),  scale=.5]
    \Tree [.{\formula{\exists y [woman' (y) \land [\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow hug'(y, x)]]: (t} \hspace{0.1cm}}  [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists y [woman' (y) \land Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \exists y [woman' (y) \land Q(x)] : (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda z. woman(z)$: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [.  \node (ne) {e$_{2}$}; ] [.{\formula{\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow saw'(j, x)] : t_{1} }} [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall (x) [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda$ x. x is a man: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k,m): (t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {k : e$_{2}$} ;] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m): (e_{2}  \rightarrow t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [. {\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y): (e_{3} \rightarrow (e_{2}  \rightarrow  t_{1})} } ] [. \node [circle,draw] (le) {m : e$_{3}$} ; ]  ]  ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:5) and +(south:5) .. (ue);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:7) and +(south:7) .. (ne);
\begin{scope}[xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-10cm]
      \Tree [.{\formula{\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow[\exists y [woman' (y) \rightarrow hug'(y, x)]]: (t} \hspace{0.1cm}}  [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] : (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda z. woman(z)$: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [.  \node (ne) {e$_{2}$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists x [woman' (y) \land saw'(j, y)] : t_{1} }} [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists (y) [woman'(y) \land Q(y)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \exists (y) [P(y) \land Q(y)]: (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda$ x. x is a man: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k,m): (t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {k : e$_{2}$} ;] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m): (e_{2}  \rightarrow t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [. {\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y): (e_{3} \rightarrow (e_{2}  \rightarrow  t_{1})} } ] [. \node [circle,draw] (me) {m : e$_{3}$} ; ]  ]  ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:2) and +(south:2) .. (ue);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:7) and +(south:7) .. (ne);
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{document}
```

[image: squished trees]

If you want the first tree on the same page, you could try this but, again, your readers will not find it easy:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\newcommand\formula[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textheight}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.S  [.DP [.D some ] [.N woman ] ] [.VP  [.V hugs ] [.DP [.D every ] [.N man ] ]]]
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \resizebox{\textheight}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \Tree [.S  [.DP [.D some ] [.N woman ] ] [.VP  [.V hugs ] [.DP [.D every ] [.N man ] ]]]
    \end{tikzpicture} {\Huge$\Rightarrow$}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center),  scale=.5]
      \Tree [.{\formula{\exists y [woman' (y) \land [\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow hug'(y, x)]]: (t} \hspace{0.1cm}}  [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists y [woman' (y) \land Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \exists y [woman' (y) \land Q(x)] : (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda z. woman(z)$: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [.  \node (ne) {e$_{2}$}; ] [.{\formula{\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow saw'(j, x)] : t_{1} }} [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall (x) [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda$ x. x is a man: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k,m): (t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {k : e$_{2}$} ;] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m): (e_{2}  \rightarrow t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [. {\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y): (e_{3} \rightarrow (e_{2}  \rightarrow  t_{1})} } ] [. \node [circle,draw] (le) {m : e$_{3}$} ; ]  ]  ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
      \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:5) and +(south:5) .. (ue);
      \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:7) and +(south:7) .. (ne);
      \begin{scope}[xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-10cm]
        \Tree [.{\formula{\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow[\exists y [woman' (y) \rightarrow hug'(y, x)]]: (t} \hspace{0.1cm}}  [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow Q(x)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] : (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda z. woman(z)$: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [.  \node (ne) {e$_{2}$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists x [woman' (y) \land saw'(j, y)] : t_{1} }} [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists (y) [woman'(y) \land Q(y)]: (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \exists (y) [P(y) \land Q(y)]: (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda$ x. x is a man: \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k,m): (t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {k : e$_{2}$} ;] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m): (e_{2}  \rightarrow t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [. {\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y): (e_{3} \rightarrow (e_{2}  \rightarrow  t_{1})} } ] [. \node [circle,draw] (me) {m : e$_{3}$} ; ]  ]  ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
        \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:2) and +(south:2) .. (ue);
        \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me)..controls +(south west:7) and +(south:7) .. (ne);
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: all in one]

Add `\centering` in the `\minipage` if you want the trees centred:

[image: centred]

I take it that the different scaling has some meaning so I've kept the relative scaling constant within the rotated box. However, the results obviously look a bit odd....

Answer (score 3):

I concur with cfr that you might want to rethink how much information you're putting on one page, particularly whether you really need the tree at the top that is then duplicated before the arrow.

Here are the space-saving changes I made. They're all independent of one another, so you can tweak to meet your needs, but I think you will find that the line breaking makes the most difference.

- **Line breaking within tree nodes.** In your semantic trees, I broke lines at colons. To allow line breaking within nodes, you will need `every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}`. I also adjusted the `level distance` to prevent the branches from getting too flat or inverting once the lines were broken.
- **Margins.** I reduced all the margins to 2.5 cm using the `geometry` package.
- **Scaling.** I used `\scalebox`, a command provided by `graphicx`, which is loaded by `tikz`. I've found that it works better than the `scale` option in `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\newcommand\formula[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

  \scalebox{.7}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.S  [.DP [.D some ] [.N woman ] ] [.VP  [.V hugs ] [.DP [.D every ] [.N man ] ]]]
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \scalebox{.6}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \Tree [.S  [.DP [.D some ] [.N woman ] ] [.VP  [.V hugs ] [.DP [.D every ] [.N man ] ]]]
    \end{tikzpicture} {\Huge$\Rightarrow$}
    }
    \scalebox{.6}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center), every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}, level distance = 9ex]
      \Tree [.{\formula{\exists y [woman' (y) \land [\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow hug'(y, x)]]:}\\\formula{(t} \hspace{0.1cm}}  [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists y [woman' (y) \land Q(x)]:}\\ \formula{(\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \exists y [woman' (y) \land Q(x)] :}\\ \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda z. woman(z)$:\\ \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):}\\\formula{(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [.  \node (ne) {e$_{2}$}; ] [.{\formula{\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow saw'(j, x)] :}\\\formula{t_{1} }} [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow Q(x)]:}\\ \formula{(\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall (x) [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)]:}\\\formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda$ x. x is a man:\\ \formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):}\\\formula{(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k,m):}\\\formula{(t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {k : e$_{2}$} ;] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m):}\\\formula{ (e_{2}  \rightarrow t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [. {\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y):}\\\formula{ (e_{3} \rightarrow (e_{2}  \rightarrow  t_{1})} } ] [. \node [circle,draw] (le) {m : e$_{3}$} ; ]  ]  ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
      \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le.south west)..controls +(south west:4) and +(south:5) .. (ue);
      \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me.south west)..controls +(-10,-3) and +(south:7) .. (ne);
      \begin{scope}[xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-12cm]
        \Tree [.{\formula{\forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow[\exists y [woman' (y) \rightarrow hug'(y, x)]]:}\\\formula{ (t} \hspace{0.1cm}}  [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [man' (x) \rightarrow Q(x)]:}\\\formula{ (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] :}\\\formula{ (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda z. woman(z)$:\\\formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):}\\\formula{(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [.  \node (ne) {e$_{2}$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists x [woman' (y) \land saw'(j, y)] :}\\\formula{ t_{1} }} [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists (y) [woman'(y) \land Q(y)]:}\\\formula{ (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))} \hspace{0.1cm}} [. { \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \exists (y) [P(y) \land Q(y)]:}\\\formula{ (e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})\rightarrow (\forall X(e_{3} \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X))}}   ] [.{$\lambda$ x. x is a man:\\\formula{(e_{4} \rightarrow t_{1})}}   ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m. saw(k,m):}\\\formula{(e_{3} \rightarrow t_{1})} } [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k,m):}\\\formula{ (t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {k : e$_{2}$} ;] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m):}\\\formula{ (e_{2}  \rightarrow t_{1}) \hspace{0.1cm}  }} [. {\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y):}\\\formula{ (e_{3} \rightarrow (e_{2}  \rightarrow  t_{1})} } ] [. \node [circle,draw] (me) {m : e$_{3}$} ; ]  ]  ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
        \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le.west)..controls +(west:1) and +(south:1) .. (ue);
        \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (me.south west)..controls +(-12,-3) and +(south:8) .. (ne);
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! And some filler.

Comment: Good. You changed the implication from classical $\rightarrow$ from the linear logic based $\linimp$ I was using.

Comment: @user65526, I didn't make any changes to the trees other than to add line breaks and adjust the arrow paths. I don't see `\linimp` anywhere in your code or mine. As @cfr mentioned in the comment on the question, your MWE didn't compile and so we defined `\formula` to be simply `\ensuremath`. Perhaps you had a different definition for it?